# Sorting Drop Down List Not by Value or Alphabetically

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have a very open ended question. I know how to sort a drop down list by value and alphabetically through jQuery. But is there a way to sort it to a customized order, that isn't by value or alphabetically?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a data-order attribute then use that value to sort the options:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/kpt19djr/1/

```
<select id="test">
    <option data-order="7">opt 1</option>
    <option data-order="4">opt 2</option>
    <option data-order="1">opt 3</option>
    <option data-order="5">opt 4</option>
    <option data-order="6">opt 5</option>
    <option data-order="2">opt 6</option>
    <option data-order="3">opt 7</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$("#test").html($("#test option").val(function(){
    return $(this).data('order');
}).sort(function (a, b) {
    var a = parseInt(a.value,10), b = parseInt(b.value,10);
    return a < b ? -1 : 1;
}));
```

Comment: This would be great if I could use the ASP.NET. In my case in needs to be done in all jQuery

Comment: But, I love the idea, I will use this in the future

Comment: What is the order you need? can you include select with its options, maybe I can help

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional field to capture the sorting order intent, sort by that field,  and hide the field from view...